# How to remove key name from AngularJS object and keep it's value?

Tags: angularjs, object, key-value, angularjs-ng-model

I have checkboxes for the days of the week. I am using ng-model however cannot use the same model for each as it prevents multiple boxes from being checked. So, as a work around I have used the following format for the model: day.sun, day.mon etc.

The object results as: $scope.day = {sun:0, mon:1}.

I need to remove the key names so that the object looks as such: $scope.day = {0, 1}

Is there a way to remove the key names? I have looked online and most examples shows deleting both the key/value pair. Object.values() was another option that I came across but I get an error that it is not defined.

I need to store that value({0,1}) into the following object:

```
$rootScope.schedule = {
           "@": {
               "let_run": "yes",
               "when_holiday": "ignore_holiday",
                "begin":"00:00",
               "end":"24:00"
           },               

           "weekdays": {            
               "day": {
                   "@": {
                       **"day": $rootScope.day,**
                   }
               }            
           },
           "monthdays": {            
               "day": {
                   "@": {
                       "day": $rootScope.startDate
                   }
               }            
           }
        };
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's not a valid object, did you mean an array like `[0, 1]`? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Polyfill for `Object.values` polyfills

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question...the object is $scope.day = {sun:0, mon:1}

Comment: No, your `{0,1}` is **not a valid object**.

Comment: This is definitely an XY Problem.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378.  Your *real* problem is how to check multiple checkboxes, but you have asked about a potential solution involving removing key names.  Unfortunately. the potential solution isn't really valid.  You should consider revisiting your true problem, and show some more details that explain why you think you can't check multiple checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use forEach. BTW  just {0,1} is not a valid object. You need to use array.

```
$scope.newObj = [];
$scope.Object={sun:0, mon:1};
angular.forEach($scope.Object,function(val,key){
    $scope.newObj.push(val);
})
```

Comment: Careful with this, object key order is not guaranteed

Comment: Thanks.
So once the values are in the array - how can I push those array values to $rootScope.schedule --> day: $rootScope.day?

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee correct key order, you should use an array of *day* keys in order

```
var day = {sun: 0, mon: 1, ... },
    days = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'],
    dayValues = days.map(function(key) {
        return day[key] || 0;
    });
```